# Running mongos as background process

Tags: mongodb

How can I run mongos as background process in an EC2 machine?

I am trying to set up a sharded cluster on EC2 machines and I am able to run mongod as background service, but I am not able to run mongos as background service.

Answer (score 19):

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log
```

Comment: and how to stop this again?

Comment: `pkill -f -9 "mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log"` this will do the job @beNerd

Answer (score 5):

To run a mongod process as a daemon (i.e. fork), and write its output to a log file, use the --fork and --logpath options. You must create the log directory; however, mongod will create the log file if it does not exist.

The following command starts mongod as a daemon and records log output to /var/log/mongodb.log.

mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log

Answer (score 4):

You need to start mongos with `--fork` parameter. It
Enables a daemon mode that runs the mongos process in the background. By default mongos does not run as a daemon: typically you will run mongos as a daemon, either by using --fork or by using a controlling process that handles the daemonization process (e.g. as with upstart and systemd).

You can also try `&` with the command to run it as background. for ex- `mongod &`

If you have ran or want to make current process to background the press `Ctrl+z` and type `bg`.